# sqlsrv выдаёт ошибку 102

Tags: php, html, sql-server

у меня есть бд в которую нужно вносить данные введённые пользователем из формы.
К бд я подключаюсь, а данные не вставляются. Вот код php:

```php
<?php
    require_once('connect.php');

    $startDay = $_POST['startDay'];
    $endDay = $_POST['endDay'];

    $targetType = $_POST['taget-type'];
    $divisionType = $_POST['division-type'];
    $fio = $_POST['fio'];
    

    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];;
    $secondName = $_POST['secondName'];
    $thirdName = $_POST['thirdName'];
    $phoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $organization = $_POST['organization'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $birthday = $_POST['birthday'];
    $seriaPassport = $_POST['seriaPassport'];
    $numberPassport = $_POST['numberPassport'];

    $photo = $_POST['uploadImage'];

    $uploadDocument = $_POST['uploadDocument'];

    //print_r($_POST);

    $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO SoloVisitTable (stardDay, endDay, targetType, divisionType, fio, secondName, firstName, thirdName, phoneNumber, email, organization, comment, birthday, seriaPassport, numberPassport, photo, uploadDocument) VALUES ($startDay, $endDay, $targetType, $divisionType, $fio, $firstName, $secondName, $thirdName, $phoneNumber, $email, $organization, $comment, $birthday, $seriaPassport, $numberPassport, $photo, $uploadDocument)"; //sql запрос

    $stmtInsert = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlInsert);

    if($stmtInsert){
        echo 'Инфа вставилась';
    }
    else{
        if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
            foreach( $errors as $error ) {
                echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
                echo "Код: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
                echo "Сообщение: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Сама проблема я думаю в запросе, но не понимаю где именно.
Вот ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то я думаю у вас значения переменных не подставились, это же всё в кавычках. Почитайте где-нибудь как в `PHP` правильно подставлять значения в `SQL` запросы, я просто не в курсе насчёт `PHP`.

Comment: Выведите текст сообщения `$error[ 'message']` в кодировке `windows-1251` с помощью функции `mb_convert_encoding` и увидите нормально читаемое сообщение. Соответственно поймете на что ругается сервер БД.

Comment: Поменял кодировку и действительно сразу понял в чём проблема. Оказывается переменные нужно было обернуть в кавычки '' (об этом как раз таки и говорит сообщение на скриншоте), а затем уже моя невнимательность была я указал не верный размер строки в sql server

Comment: А теперь подумай что будет если у тебя в каком-то поле также будет кавычка)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-escape-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 вам поможет в экранировании строк